# Ngrx effect is not being selected when action i being dispatched in unit testing

Tags: jestjs, ngrx

I am trying to test my effects. I have notice that, when I dispatch the action using **replaySubject**, SearchEffects class is being called. However, this.actions$ is undefined. Therefore, the right effect, **search$** in this case, is not being selected.

```
 let actions$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
 let effects: SearchEffects;

 beforeEach(async() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      provideMockActions(() => actions$)
    ]
  });

  effects = TestBed.inject<SearchEffects>(SearchEffects);
});

it('should call register method when "Search" is dispatched', () => {
  actions$.next(search({
    context: { location: 'test' }
  }));

 effects.search$.subscribe();
});

readonly search$ = createEffect(
() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(     //actions$ IS NULL
    ofType(search),       //THIS EFFECT IS NOT BEING SELECTED. 
    tap((action) => {
      //...               //I PUT MY BREAKPOINT HERE ... BUT NOTHING IS HAPPENING
    })
  ),
  { dispatch: false }
);
```